# Python transform array 1D

Tags: python, cuml

I have a array which has this output and your type is cupy.ndarray:

```
x = array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       ...,
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

I want is output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])
```

I tried use transpose and np.expand_dims and had the outputs:

```
x.transpose()

# Output
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])

np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)

#Output
array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: `[arr[0] for arr in x]`

Comment: If you just want to make it 1d, `x.flatten()`

Comment: Do `x = x.reshape(-1)`.  That tells is to keep the same number of elements but make it a 1D array instead of a 2D array.

Comment: or `x.ravel()` so many options.

Comment: or `x.T.squeeze()`...

Comment: FWIW, `reshape` is quite efficient, because it doesn't change the array.  It just changes the interpretation.

Comment: FWIW, `ravel()` is also normally a view into the same date.